# Narrowing conversion to bool warning in MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++

When compiling this code:

```
enum B: bool { T = true };
struct A { bool member; };

void foo(const B b = T)
{
    A a{b}; // warning here
}

void bar()
{
    const B b = T;
    A a{b};
}
```

MSVC issues a warning in `foo`:

> warning C4838: conversion from 'const B' to 'bool' requires a narrowing conversion

but compiles `bar` fine.

Here is a [proof](https://godbolt.org/z/Zkmrvu)

Is it a compiler bug or intended behavior?

Comment: My guess is that you're running into an [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) issue, where it's doing integer promotion. Based on my reading of CPPReference this isn't UB and is allowed but MS is letting you know it's technically a narrowing conversion.

Comment: does it fix the warning to change `enum B` to `enum class B` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant part of the definition of [narrowing conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#Narrowing_conversions) is in C++17 [dcl.init.list]/7:

> A narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion:
>
> - [...]
> - from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to an integer type that cannot represent all the values of the original type, except where the source is a constant expression whose value after integral promotions will fit into the target type.

In your code `B` is an unscoped enumeration with a fixed underlying type of `bool`.  In [dcl.enum]/8 it says:

> For an enumeration whose underlying type is fixed, the values of the enumeration are the values of the underlying type

which means that the only possible values of `B` are the values of `bool`, i.e. `true` and `false`. It cannot hold other values.

Since `A::member` can in fact represent all values of `B` then it is not a narrowing conversion,  so the warning is bogus.